# Perl export/parse data from large block of text

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, export

I am trying to export specific data from a large block of continuous text. I understand PERL was designed for doing such a thing. 
From the examples on the internet and including here I have some clues on how to go about it, however I am unable to carry or modify something immediately across to my problem.

I believe what I am doing is quite simple.

Example raw data (rawdata.txt) appears so:

```
<id>0001</id><first name>John</first name><last name>Smith</last name><height>180</height><weight>95</weight><id>0002</id><first name>David</first name><last name>Jones</last
name><height>175</height><weight>120</weight><id>0003</id><first name>Jacob</first 
name><last name>Fitzpatrick</last name><height>165</height><weight>105</weight>
```

(it is not conveniently separated by line, just one continuous block)

**Goal 1 output** is to output to a file (or just print to screen) the ids of all the people present in the rawdata as a comma-separated line (so scan the file for all info that is contained within id tags)

Example goal 1 output from above rawdata:

```
0001,0002,0003
```

Related but not independent, goal 2 output is to print (again on the screen or to a file, doesn't matter) the first name together with last name, and then height, on a line-by-line basis for each person

Example goal 2 output from above rawdata:

```
John Smith, 180
David Jones, 175
Jacob Fitzpatrick, 165
```

What we are really trying to do is a bit more complicated than that, but I'm sure if we can get the above outputs then we can expand and modify as necessary.

Also happy to take a look at any resources that pertain to very similar things to what we are trying to do here

Thanks and kind regards,
SK

Comment: The data is XML so you should use an XML parser and not regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Your data are similar to XML. If you fix the format (i.e. by changing `<first name>` to `<first_name>`, you can use a proper XML parser to do the hard work. For example, this is how to get the expected output in [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
open data.xml ;
echo xsh:join(',', //id) ;
for //first_name
    echo :s (.) " " following-sibling::last_name[1] ", " following-sibling::height[1] ;
```

Comment: Thanks Sniffer and Choroba for getting back to us.

Something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_display_table 
is similar to what we are trying to do.

Question is, how the heck can we do this. Is there a program that almost completely replicates what the website has done? i.e. load up an XML file of raw data (cd_catalog.xml in that example), have a big box where can insert the 'source  code' and then display the output/'Result' ?

Basically exactly what the website has done, but offline and using our own 'cd_catalog.xml' instead of theirs? Since thanks, SK

Comment: @SergeiKrutznetski: If you install `xsh`, you can run the script I gave you and get the expected output at STDOUT.

Answer (score 0):

using simple regex,

```
            if ( m/<id>(.*?)</)
                    {
                        push(@rrr, $1);
                    }
            my $id = join(',', @rrr);
            print $id;
```

This will give you the ids, a slight modification of the regex will get you the first names, last names and the height you require.. 
Kinda noobish because I am kinda new to Perl and somebody helped me with a similar regex. Hopefully this helps..